# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory laradock?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laradock

I work in ubuntu. 
I install laradock, after laravel and all work fine. 
But, i study the lesson with migration, and when i try to apply command `php artisan migrate`, i get an error from the question.

My dbconfig

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=tlaravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

The command to start laradock for me is `docker-compose up -d nginx php-fpm mysql phpmyadmin workspace`

And i can go to phpmyadmin to address localhost:8084, and the data for phpmyadmin is

```
server: mysql
login: root
pass: root.
```

But i don't know what login and password to write in .env file for mysql, i wrote the data for phpmyadmin.

In .env from laradock, the version of mysql is latest. 
I use laravel 5.2, because is my first course with this version.

I hope you will help me. 
Thansk.